# How do you complete Green Hills of Stranglethorn World of Warcraft quest after the zone phases to 85?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Question is same as the title.  How do you complete The Green Hills of Stranglethorn (World of Warcraft) quest once the zone has phased to level 85?  NVM, I know now.  You have to finish all the quests for level 85, leave the zone and come back.  Everything resets once you do this.

Comment: You might want to post your own findings as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You answered it yourself. The zone is phased only while the quests are active. Either complete them or abandon them and you can do whatever you want there.